# Innodb error log sequence number is in future

Tags: mysql, innodb, windows, wamp

```
2020-08-28 16:46:02 d64 InnoDB: Error: page 1 log sequence number 23113680
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 3181581.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
```

I'm using VM and OS is Windows Server 2016 and Uniform Server.
MySQL stops upon this error and doesn't work until it is restarted.
After restarting, it runs for some hours and stops again.
How to overcome this?

Comment: I've seen a few instances of this error in various bug report. I'd suggest ensuring the mysql is of the latest version. It looks line Uniform Server is bundling older versions. Which is the mysql version you have?

Comment: MySQL Ver 14.14

Comment: Have you removed any files lately. I was getting this error recently after recovering from a corrupt redo log on a non-production server (I removed the ib_logfiles to fix the problem). But afterwards I got the same error for a few days until the sequence number caught up.

Comment: @IGGt yes I have removed ib_logfiles as there were error related to access rights and eventually ended up in this. So it'l work fine afrer few days?

Comment: For me it only took about two and a bit days. But I guess it depends on how busy your database is, and so how quickly the logs catch up.